# Is netty CompositeByteBuf direct or indirect

Tags: java, netty

I'm using netty 4.1.0 beta3 to send 2 buffers in a row:

```
channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(byteBuf1, byteBuf2));
```

The use of Unpooled.wrappedBuffer() is recommanded by netty javadoc.

However, the source code of Unpooled passes "false" as "direct" parameter when create the composite buffer.

Does it means, the result buffer will be treated as indirect buffer(which is slower) when sent through the socket, even byteBuf1 and byteBuf2 are both direct buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it will not use a direct buffer when expand the composite buffer. If both buffers are direct that are used to create the composite buffer it will for sure be direct.

Answer (score 0):

It does **not** look like the `CompositeByteBuf` created using `Unpooled` is direct:

From 4.0.32 Unpooled.java:

```
public static ByteBuf wrappedBuffer(int maxNumComponents, ByteBuf... buffers) {
        switch (buffers.length) {
        ...
        default:
            for (ByteBuf b: buffers) {
                if (b.isReadable()) {
                    return new CompositeByteBuf(ALLOC, --> false <--, maxNumComponents, buffers);
                }
            }
        }
        return EMPTY_BUFFER;
    }
```